# Clearing elements from a CCBI file from CCTextureCache and CCSpriteFrameCache

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Currently i'm making a game using cocos2d and i've come up on a situation that i'm having trouble dealing with. The game has a loading screen that uses a CCB file and is read in using CCBReader and this causes it to be added to the caches. After the user exits the loading screen and enters the game i would like to clear the textures that the loading screen uses from the cache. I know you can use something like

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeSpriteFrameByName:item];
[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeTextureForKey:item];
```

but this doesn't clear it from the texture when loaded from a CCB file. Any body have this situation before or knows how to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate and use a `CCSpriteFrameCache` and `CCTextureCache` for your own assets. Then clear the shared caches completely:

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeSpriteFrames];
[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeAllTextures];
```